# How effectively search alternatives with rgrep in Emacs

Tags: emacs, grep

I'm trying to find where in the code base of OpenERP both the names "default_debit_account_id" and "default_credit_account_id" are used.

If I search them separately they both yield more than 20 results.  However if I try <kbd>M-x</kbd>`rgrep`<kbd>RET</kbd>`\bdefault_(debit|credit)_account_id\b`<kbd>RET</kbd> this time no results are retrived. I have tried also placing a single ("\") and double slashes ("\") before the parentheses, but it didn't help.

Ultimately this is the command run by Emacs

```
find . -type d \( -path \*/SCCS -o -path \*/RCS -o -path \*/CVS -o -path \*/MCVS -o \
       -path \*/.svn -o -path \*/.git -o -path \*/.hg -o -path \*/.bzr -o \
       -path \*/_MTN -o -path \*/_darcs -o -path \*/\{arch\} \) -prune -o \
       \! -type d \( -name .\#\* -o -name \*.o -o -name \*\~ -o -name \*.bin -o -name \*.lbin -o -name \*.so -o -name \*.a -o -name \*.ln -o -name \*.blg -o -name \*.bbl -o -name \*.elc -o -name \*.lof -o -name \*.glo -o -name \*.idx -o -name \*.lot -o -name \*.fmt -o -name \*.tfm -o -name \*.class -o -name \*.fas -o -name \*.lib -o -name \*.mem -o -name \*.x86f -o -name \*.sparcf -o -name \*.dfsl -o -name \*.pfsl -o -name \*.d64fsl -o -name \*.p64fsl -o -name \*.lx64fsl -o -name \*.lx32fsl -o -name \*.dx64fsl -o -name \*.dx32fsl -o -name \*.fx64fsl -o -name \*.fx32fsl -o -name \*.sx64fsl -o -name \*.sx32fsl -o -name \*.wx64fsl -o -name \*.wx32fsl -o -name \*.fasl -o -name \*.ufsl -o -name \*.fsl -o -name \*.dxl -o -name \*.lo -o -name \*.la -o -name \*.gmo -o -name \*.mo -o -name \*.toc -o -name \*.aux -o -name \*.cp -o -name \*.fn -o -name \*.ky -o -name \*.pg -o -name \*.tp -o -name \*.vr -o -name \*.cps -o -name \*.fns -o -name \*.kys -o -name \*.pgs -o -name \*.tps -o -name \*.vrs -o -name \*.pyc -o -name \*.pyo \) -prune -o  \
       -type f \( -name \*.py \) \
       -exec grep -i -nH -e \\bdefault_\(debit\|credit\)_account_id\\b {} +
```

Thus `grep` sees the pattern (after shell escaping is perfomed) `\bdefault_(debit|credit)_account_id\b`.  What's wrong with this? How should I search this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Emacs flavor of regex](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression): `\bdefault_\(debit\|credit\)_account_id\b`.

Comment: Ah! So the `\|` was the culprit.

Comment: Yes, but I have tried the `\(` and `\)` but missed the `\|`. Thanks.